# Haskell: How to stop program printing Left or Right

Tags: haskell, types

I've made a calculator in haskell which I run from within GHCi. However since the final number can be an integer or double I've made the type declaration

```
calc :: String -> Either Integer Double
```

However the output of the function always has either left or right in front of it for example

```
Left 7

Right 8.4
```

Is there a way I can stop the left and right being printed?

Answer (score 9):

### The fancy way

*(Probably, the other, less fancy solution below is better for you)*

If you're only concerned about ghci, there's now (GHC>=7.6) [the possibility to use a custom print function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-interactive-print). You'd just specify, say,

```
type CalcResult = Either Integer Double

calcPrint :: CalcResult -> IO()
calcPrint (Left intg) = print intg
calcPrint (Right floatng) = print floatng
```

and then load ghci by

> $ ghci YourModule.hs -interactive-print=YourModule.calcPrint SpecPrinter

This way, it's going to be a bit annoying: `calcPrint` can *only* use `CalcResult`, so you wouldn't be able to display anything else. To get around this, you can use a type class,

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

data CalcResult            -- We must prevent the 'Show' instance of 'Either' from
   = IntegerResult Integer -- getting in our way. (This type is better anyway,
   | FloatingResult Double -- you might want to add more types (e.g. 'Complex')
                           -- later, which is no good with 'Either'.)

class CalcShow c where
  calcShow :: c -> String

instance (Show c) => CalcShow c where
  calcShow = show

instance CalcShow CalcResult where
  calcShow (IntegerResult intg) = show intg
  calcShow (FloatingResult floatng) = show floatng

calcPrint :: CalcShow c => c -> IO()
calcPrint = putStrLn . calcShow
```

This way you will be able to display calculation results the way you'd like, as well as anything in the old `Show` class:

> $ ghci-7.6 GHCI_Customprint.hs -interactive-print=GHCI_Customprint.calcPrint
>   GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>   Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package base ... linking ... done.
>   [1 of 1] Compiling GHCI_Customprint ( GHCI_Customprint.hs, interpreted )
>   Ok, modules loaded: GHCI_Customprint.
>   *GHCI_Customprint> "blubb"
>   "blubb"
>   *GHCI_Customprint> [1..5]
>   [1,2,3,4,5]
>   *GHCI_Customprint> IntegerResult 39
>   39
>   *GHCI_Customprint> FloatingResult $ -236.24983e+89
>   -2.3624983e91

### The other solution

As I said, you should be using a custom data type as your result, not `Either`. Why, if you have such a type you might as well give it a `Show` instance that does what you want:

```
instance Show CalcResult where
  show (IntegerResult intg) = show intg
  show (FloatingResult floatng) = show floatng
```

For your purposes, this will probably be just fine, you can use it in ghci without any extra tweaks and it does what you want. Only, there's a kind of law that a `Show` instance should produce valid Haskell code. But that's actually ok, because you can make `3` or `27.8` valid "constructors" for `CalcResult`!

```
instance Num CalcResult where
  fromInteger = IntegerResult
  IntegerResult a + IntegerResult b = IntegerResult $ a+b
  ...

instance Floating CalcResult where
  fromRational = FloatingResult . fromRational
  ...
```

Answer (score 9):

When you evaluate this function, GHCi automatically calls `putStrLn . show` on the result. It is the `show` function for `Either Integer Double` which is adding the `Left` and `Right` strings.

To avoid this, you can use `either show show` instead, which will apply the `show` function only to the numbers stored inside the `Either`, so

```
> putStrLn . either show show $ calc ...
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: Even better, define your own print function: `p = putStrLn . either show show`.