# Why are unpack and show defined differently in Data.Text (and behave differently for non-ASCII characters?)

Tags: haskell

`unpack` and `show` are two ways to convert `Text` to a `String`. They, however, behave and are defined differently for non-ASCII characters:

```
Prelude Data.Text> putStrLn $ unpack $ pack "你好我的朋友"
你好我的朋友
Prelude Data.Text> putStrLn $ show $ pack "你好我的朋友"
"\20320\22909\25105\30340\26379\21451"
```

With `show`, I believe, returning a string of codepoints, while `unpack` displays the actual characters. I have found this to be a nuisance while coding, as I had defined functions that take a `Show` instance and wanted to pass in `Text`, and expected it to return the actual non-ASCII characters as a `String`.

What was the design intent for this behavior? Why were `show` and `unpack` defined differently?

The source can be found at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.5/doc/html/src/Data-Text.html.

Comment: Where comes the utf-8 from? "'Text' value is represented as packed UTF-16 data". I can't find any notation of utf-8 in pack/unpack.

Comment: I guess I meant non-ASCII, and just wrote UTF-8. I'll change it to say "Non-ASCII"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a general thing about `Show`: it's intended rather to produce a kind of *preview* of objects that can double as a portable serialisation, readable **as Haskell code**. Obviously, `你好我的朋友` is *not* valid Haskell (unless you define it as a variable, which you actually [can](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/hashiwokakero-build-bridges/4824#4824)!), so it would not be acceptable as output of `show`. It would be quite ok if it produced `"你好我的朋友"` (in fact, I would prefer that), but this might cause Platform etc. problems when you're not throughoutly using full UTF-8 in all of your work chain, so the safer expansion to ASCII was chosen.

If you want the nice non-escaped plain-string output as the GHCi echo, you can use [the new custom-pretty-printer feature](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-interactive-print). I already wrote something about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267320/haskell-how-to-stop-program-printing-left-or-right/16267402#16267402).